# I just left Vietnam. Can I get a new 14-day free entry if I go back sooner than 30 days?

Tags: visas, vietnam

I flew from Vietnam to the Philippines a few days ago. If I go back to Vietnam again and land in Saigon, can I still get a new 14-day free entry? Or do I need to stay outside of the country for more than 31 days first?

Answer (score 2):

The 14-day free entry requires a 30-day interval. If you need to go back sooner than that to Vietnam, you'll need a visa (possibly an e-visa).